# I need use two different tables from idataset (DBUnit), how i can do this?

Tags: java, dbunit

I need use two different tables from idataset (DBUnit), how i can do this?

```
@Override
protected IDataSet getDataSet() throws Exception {
    return new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(loadFile("dao/group/dataSet.xml"));
}
```

for one tables?

Comment: Can you please clarify what seems to be the issue? Do you want to load 2 data sets from 2 different files?

Answer (score 1):

Use `IDataSet.getTable(String tableName)` to use a specific table from it.

Comment: Did this solve the problem or are there more issues?